# 1 Help with installing Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, nouveau

I am trying to install an Nvidia driver for the GeForce GTX 750 Ti graphics card I have but I am running into some issues in the process. Running Ubuntu 14.04. Essentially, I have followed the instruction here:

http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/

I looked up the correct driver to use (nvidia-352) and ran

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

but when I verify the installation using

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

I get:

```
Kernal driver in use: nouveau
```

rather than:

```
Kernal driver in use: nvidia
```

Running the following command confirms that the nouveau drivers are being blacklisted:

```
grep 'nouveau' /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep nvidia

/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-352_hybrid.conf:blacklist nouveau
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-352_hybrid.conf:blacklist lbm-nouveau
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-352_hybrid.conf:alias nouveau off
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-352_hybrid.conf:alias lbm-nouveau off
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf:blacklist nouveau
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf:blacklist lbm-nouveau
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf:alias nouveau off
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf:alias lbm-nouveau off
```

I assume that this would explain why I get thrown into low graphics mode upon restart because the graphics card is trying to use a driver that is blacklisted.

I have also found that running the command `lsmod | grep nvidia` returns nothing.

Essentially my question is how do I switch the 'kernel driver in use' from nouveau to nvidia?

Answer (score 1):

People following outdated Nvidia guides is becoming a real issue round here.

First remove that driver and the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get update
```

Now add this PPA and install the driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Now when the restart is complete, you will be using the Nvidia driver by default.